# Laravel Testing for update user data when logged in

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, testing

I am doing feature testing for my Laravel application. I am trying to update an authenticated user data. I am using actingAs to authenticate my user in my test code and then trying to post with some data to update that user data. But I am getting "Call to a member function update() on null" error.

This problem only happening on test case. original application working fine.

```
public function an_authenticated_account_user_with_valid_role_can_change_2fa_option()
    {
      $this->withoutExceptionHandling();
      //preventing middlewares
      $this->withoutMiddleware(\App\Application\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class);
      $attributes = [
        'two_step' => 'no'
      ];
      $response = $this->actingAs($this->validRoleUser, 'account')
                ->post('/account/security/change-2fa', $attributes);
      $response->assertStatus(200);
      $response->assertSee('Please select an option');
    }
```

I am getting this error message during test above code:

Call to a member function update() on null

Comment: Where is your update query?

Comment: You act as `$this->validRoleUser` in your _TEST_ code, but not in your endpoint.

What you should have to do is authenticate on your endpoint as an valid user and then call the update.

For more help, we need to know your architecture (how get users logged in, via OAuth, or?)

Comment: Hello @farooq, here is my update query:  
`public function securityUpdate($request)
  {
    if ($this->dataValidation($request) != false)
    {
      $userId      = $this->repo->getUser('id');
      $this->repo->update(['two_step' => $request['two_step']], $userId);

      $success          = [];
      $success['msg']   = 'You have successfully changed your 2fa option';
      return response()->json($success, $this->successStatus);
    }
    else
    {
      return response()->json(['error'=>'Please select an option'], 401);
    }
  }`

Comment: Hello @Paladin
I have assigned  validRoleUser as private at the top.

`private $validRoleUser;

  /**
   * Setup method
   */

  public function setUp() :void
  {

    parent::setUp();




    $this->validRoleUser = factory(Account::class)
                         ->create([
                             'password' => Hash::make('Tonmoy_17'),
                             'status'   => 'active'
                         ]);
    $this->validRoleUser->assignRole('Owner');


  }`